# DataGrid in Windows form not maintaining state after adding records without database

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a requirement i have a datagrid in windows form application and i have to add record each time i submit a Book button from the form directly without database connection.It works fine for the first time but for 2nd time it is not maintaining state.So the main question is how to maintain that state.[image]

So to maintain state please do the following coading.

Declare a Datatable globally.

```
public partial class LunchDinnerBookingEntry : Form
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Now the second thing is to add a Method like this.

```
 public void createnewrow()
    {
        if(dt.Rows.Count<=0)
        {

            DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("PERSONAL NO", typeof(int));
            DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("NAME", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("DATE", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("QUANTITY", typeof(int));
            DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("TYPE", typeof(string));


            dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc4);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc5);



            dt.Rows.Add(txt_personalNo.Text, txt_name.Text, txt_date.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txt_quantity.Text), cmb_type.SelectedItem.ToString());


            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
        else
        {

            dt.Rows.Add(txt_personalNo.Text, txt_name.Text, txt_date.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txt_quantity.Text), cmb_type.SelectedItem.ToString());


            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }










    }
```

Now call this method on Book button Click.

```
 private void btn_book_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool res = false;
        createnewrow();


    }
```

It will work fine and Maintain state as follow

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` in your else statement